Implementing the simple authentication user-enrollment flow stuck at step 11
I'm doing a Implementing the simple authentication user-enrollment and stuck in step 11 and 12.
text
type here

In the step 11, it said that when user authentiacte successful, it will return:
HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
Content-Length: 0
Location: apple-remotemanagement-user-login://authentication-results?access-token=dXNlci1pZGVudGl0eQ

I do on BE - Java Spring Boot Application:
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setLocation(URI.create(URI.create("apple-remotemanagement-user-login://authentication-results?access-token=dXNlci1pZGVudGl0eQ")
return ResponseEntity.status(308).headers(headers)

and on ReactJs app, I just do call post API to get that response.
But it won't work.
Please help me check step 11 and step 12 on that proceess. Thanks
Try step 11 but won't work. So I need to verify that I'm doing right in the step 11.

The Apple guide link is here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/user_enrollment/onboarding_users_with_account_sign-in/implementing_the_simple_authentication_user-enrollment_flow
